# "I have no charge on my cellphone" or "my cellphone is out of charge"?

Tags: word-choice

Situation:
The batteries in your cellphone are running out of charge.

How would a native English speaker quickly and naturally describe this situation?

Comment: I'd have combined this with your near-identical question on cell phone account credit: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/i-have-no-money-on-my-cell-phone-account-or-my-cellphone-is-out-of-money-or-h

Comment: I'd keep them separate. We already have enough questions [asking for several things at once](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4385/compound-sentences-the-punctuation-and-mooore).

Comment: @Reg: A question about a phone account and an almost identical question about a phone battery?? And the similarity between the answers too...

Comment: @CJM: my point is that if there are X possible answers to question 1, and Y possible answers to question 2, then combining the questions gets you X*Y possible answers to choose from. Besides, I have a feeling that we are only having this discussion because the two questions have been posted by the same user in rapid succession. Had they been posted by different users on separate occasions, we probably wouldn't want to merge them (though we might cross-link), as they are ultimately asking about two different things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My phone is out of juice

This is how a nerd would describe the situation

> My phone has died on me

This is how many people refer to this situation

> My phone needs to be recharged

This is also a way to express the same fact

> I need to charge my phone

Indirect method

> Is there a cell-phone charger nearby

Another indirect method.

> Can I use your cell-phone?

Cannot always be used effectively :-(

Answer (score 5):

The most common expression I've heard for expressing that a cell phone no longer had power is:

> My cell phone battery is dead.

While holding the cell phone, many people omit the words `cell phone` since it is understood that the thing they are holding is the subject of the statement:

> My battery is dead.

Alternatively, many people omit the word `battery` since it is understood that the battery is the *dead* part of the cell phone:

> My cell phone is dead.

People will also say their cell phone is dead if it is broken via some other means, though, such as it being dropped.

Answer (score 4):

> My cell phone battery is almost flat

or

> My cell phone is almost out of power

Comment: Another more colloquial alternative is 'My phone's almost dead.'

Comment: I'd go with "My phone's battery is almost dead"... because w/o "battery" it could mean your phone itself is dying.

Comment: @Elendil: My [phone|cell|mobile|mobile phone|handy|cell phone|cellular phone|moby] ['s battery] is [almost] [dead|flat|out of power|out of juice|drained].  There are a thousand colloquial combinations, but my suggestion will be understood by vast majority of English-speakers.

Comment: @jae - I think the majority of people in the English-speaking world will assume that when a [battery-powered device] is `dead` that the battery has run out, rather than the device being broken.

Comment: @CJM: I know, I wasn't criticising, just adding.

Comment: @CJM Now, can we get that as a railroad diagram?  ;-)

Comment: @jae - I wouldn't. A phone dying or being almost dead (as opposed to being dead) is very rare.

Comment: @Elindil - sorry, didn't mean to be curt - my point was that there are *numerous* alternatives, depending where you are.

Comment: @jae: The irony is that I had to look up 'railroad diagrams' - we'd call them flow diagrams... :)

Comment: And can it be: "I'm almost out of power".?

Answer (score 1):

All the examples given so far are good, but I would also offer as common expressions

> My (cell) phone is almost out of batteries

or

> I’m almost out of batteries

or

> My phone’s battery is dying

or

> My phone is dying

Comment: Or: My phone is running out of charge. Or: I am running out of charge.

Comment: “My phone is out of batteries” sounds to me like someone has taken out the batteries (how many phones have multiple batteries?). In the singular it works: “My phone’s almost out of battery”.

Answer (score -3):

My Phone battery is getting discharged.

Comment: Not unless your phone [why the capital p, incidentally?] battery has been in the army. Getting discharged is not something that happens to a battery.