# "I have no money on my cell phone account" or "my cellphone is out of money" or how?

Tags: word-choice

Situation:

Soon you will not be able to use your cell phone because you almost have no money left on your cell phone account.

How would a native English speaker quickly and naturally describe this situation?

Comment: "I've almost **run out of** credit."

Comment: credits on the east side of the pond, minutes on the west.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say:

> I'm almost out of phone credit.

If the context was clear (i.e. you were holding your phone or speaking on the phone) you could even just say:

> I'm almost out of credit.

Comment: _I am almost out of credit_ is what I would say.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you don't use contractions? ;-)

Comment: I have some difficulties to pronounce a contracted word. ;-)

Comment: Equally valid kiamlaluno.

Answer (score 6):

Many people say "minutes" to refer to cell phone credit (because cell phone plans often measure your available balance in minutes of talking time). In my experience it's common to say "I'm almost out of minutes" or "I have only 10 minutes left on my plan" or something similar. (This is from an American perspective, if it matters)

Comment: I never run out of minutes, but I do run out of messages.  Unlike those other answerers, I would never refer to these as *credits*.  Also US perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> My credit balance is near finished

Or you could say what we usually do in India

> I have expended my cellphone balance

Answer (score 1):

> My mobile is almost out of credit

I'm not sure on the context for this question, but the above states the case. I regard the implications (that I will not be able make calls when out of credit) as implicit.

Comment: I'd leave off the "account", it's still clear.  And lots of people would leave off "phone" too I think ;-)

Comment: And similarly in the UK "My mobile (or 'phone') is almost out of credit".

Comment: @Colin/Jae: I agree... I wasn't sure of context, so I was being rather conservative.

Answer (score 0):

I would say:

> I am almost out of phone credit.

Answer (score -1):

I would say

> I need more credits.

Comment: That doesn't make sense to me.