# What word describes what to do when you have run out of credit on the phone?

Tags: word-choice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“I have no money on my cell phone account” or “my cellphone is out of money” or how?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10085/i-have-no-money-on-my-cell-phone-account-or-my-cellphone-is-out-of-money-or)

What do I need to do, when I have run out of credit for my cell phone?

Comment: I've always stumbled with this one as well! In Portuguese we sometimes say the equivalent to "(re)charge", but that obviously can create ambiguity with the battery charging sense...

Answer (score 5):

In most of the world I think **top up** is well understood. Where I've been in Asia and Africa, the booth attendant or store clerk will also understand if you ask to **add units**.

"Top up" is known in the U.S., being the terminology used by MetroPCS, Boost Mobile, NET10, and of course Virgin Mobile. The major prepaid providers, however— T-Mobile, AT&T, Verizon Wireless— all use **refill**. Because pre-paid mobile plans are not as prevalent in the U.S., I would always specify that it is your phone whether you are topping up, refilling, **adding credit**, or **adding minutes**.

Note that in the U.S. one can **top off**, but this refers to filling something completely that was already mostly full, for example when fueling up your car.

Comment: I haven't heard *top up* in the US. The norm is to *add* time, credits, or minutes.

Comment: If you go to the websites of the companies I noted above, they all use *top up*, so while the phrase may not be common it is not unknown.

Comment: In the US from the average person on the street I hear "I need to add minutes to my phone", in the UK I hear "I need to top up my phone".

Answer (score 4):

In the UK, at least, you need to *top up*.

Comment: In Australia too.

Answer (score 2):

In Australia, you need to 'recharge'.

e.g. 'I can't make any phonecalls until I recharge.'

Comment: In the UK the reason you can't make any calls until you **recharge** will always be understood to mean your mobile's battery is running out, not your talktime credit.

Comment: ^@FumbleFingers ... Same in the US.

Comment: In Australia we just say 'I need to charge my phone'. I'm sure there are a few exceptions but 'recharge' is generally understood in terms of needing to buy phone credit.

Answer (score 2):

“Can you tell me where I can purchase some credit for my mobile phone.” Should work, unless you are in the wrong part of town where they will think you are a bit posh.