# What is it called when you “refill” a debit card?

Tags: expressions, word-usage, american-english, finance

How it is called (in the US) when you go to the bank or an ATM to add cash to your VISA/MasterCard debit card? That is, when you add cash to the bank account which is tied to  that card.

Is it either of these two, or is it something else?

- to refill my debit card
- to add funds to my debit card

Comment: may be because Cash is Liquid

Comment: Somewhat related: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/58413/2085

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Your question reveals a mindset about debit cards that simply doesn't exist in the US. Here, bank accounts came first, many many decades before anyone dreamed of electronic transactions. Thus, people have debit cards because they have bank accounts, not the other way around. You don't go out and get a debit card; you go out and open an account at a bank. This also means that you simply don't talk about refilling a debit card, because it was never filled in the first place.

You *can* say something like "I need to put money in my account" or "I need to go to the bank to make a deposit", but at no point would you mention your debit card, any more than you would mention your car keys when you're planning to drive somewhere.

There *are* some debit-card-like things that do have an upper limit and can be "refilled" — store gift cards, whatever they're calling food stamps nowadays, MetroCards, that sort of thing — but they're not called "debit cards", at least not without qualification.

Comment: not true, Martha, see my comment under your comment under Kris' answer.

Comment: There are segments of the population that use a card with no associated bank account. These Stored Value cards are given as gifts to the young, used to pay wages by some employers to those who choose not to open a bank account, and used to give unemployment benefits in some U.S. states.

Comment: @KristinaLopez: see my edit -- in my experience, those types of cards aren't called "debit cards".

Comment: Stored value cards are a recent development, the popularity of which is pertinent to the apps generation not boomers. e.g., foodstamps are now ebt debit cards - they get topped-up or refilled by the govt every month.

Comment: I see your point Martha - reversing my -1. :-)

Comment: I guess what you generally have to do is transfer money from savings to checking.

Comment: +1 Well said. This also applies to many other countries, probably to most. We don't "fill up" debit cards in Holland either: a card is just a way to access your account. Gift cards and pre-paid cards are called that, not debit cards.

Comment: I'm used to the checking account card = debit card model. I recently heard a commercial on the radio for a refillable debit card and was really wondering why I'd want that. They weren't calling it a debit card, it had some brand-specific name they were obviously hoping to make into a popular thing.

Comment: "... about debit cards that simply doesn't exist in the US" -- shows you understand the concept. Question relates not to "debit cards because they have bank accounts". And incidentally, you have yourself mentioned "debit-card-like things that do have an upper limit and can be *refilled* " -- You should naturally have rearranged your answer to match the question.

Comment: Sorry, finally, I had to down vote.

Comment: @MarkAllen, maybe you're not the target market. The main benefit is for people who can't get a credit card but want some way to pay electronically which doesn't expose their main bank account to fraud.

Comment: @Kris, the point is, those aren't actually called "debit cards", at least not by anybody native to the USA. It's off-topic on this site to explain the possibilities and vagaries of the US electronic financial landscape; what is *on* topic is the language used, and in US English, you simply don't talk about adding money to a debit card. Other kinds of cards, yes; prepaid cellphones, yes; but not debit cards, because that would be like saying you need to take your car keys in to the shop.

Comment: @Peter Taylor I see, thanks! This was a really interesting question.

Comment: Incidentally, I was talking about your answer, not the question. I suggested that you amend your answer in line with what is asked in the question.

Comment: The up voter: What can you contribute to the process here apart from the gratuitous up vote? http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92857/what-is-it-called-when-you-refill-a-debit-card/92876#comment187490_92867

Comment: @Kris: I *have* answered the question. The question was, "what do they call narf-farbling in Elbonia", and the answer is "they don't *do* narf-farbling in Elbonia, so there's no word for it". I'm sorry you don't agree with my answer; if your disagreement stems from direct experience with US English usage of debit cards (not debit-card-like things, but things that are actually *called* "debit cards"), then please detail it in your answer. Your profile doesn't reveal anything about you, so it's hard to tell where you're coming from.

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/a/92869/14666 http://english.stackexchange.com/a/92876/14666

Answer (score 14):

If this a debit card that is linked to an existing account, you might say you were "adding funds to my account" or "making a deposit."

If this is a [Stored Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stored-value_card) card (perhaps bought from the store or used to disburse wages), then several providers say *add funds to my card* (e.g., Walmart). At Cardrex you may *[reload](http://cardrex.com/?page=default)* your card.

Square 1 calls itself a "Stored Value Debit Card provider." (These are neither mass transit cards nor store gift cards. They bear a MasterCard or Visa logo and I believe that this may be what the OP was aiming for.) It asks in its [FAQ](http://www.square1ltd.com/pages/public_faq.asp), "How Do I Put Money On My Square 1 Stored Value Card?"

In its answers, here are some other synonyms that Square 1 uses:

- Put Money on
- Loading funds
- Adding funds
- Have money placed on.

---

EDIT 1: Another term: reload

EDIT 2: Adding that Square 1 calls its cards "Stored Value Debit Cards" and listing Square 1 synonyms.

Comment: The company refers to it as "Stored Value **Debit Card**."

Comment: Yes, assertions to the contrary, Square 1 calls it a Stored Value Debit card. It is not linked to a traditional bank account. The answer to the FAQ I quote above says "As a Square 1 Cardholder you have multiple options to loading (adding) funds to your Square 1™ Stored Value Debit Card. You can...arrange to have money placed on your Square 1™ Stored Value Debit Card." So there are several answers for the OP: *Put Money on, loading, add funds to, have money placed on*.

Comment: You can edit-in that detail into your answer for all to see.

Comment: Like I said, "...but they're not called 'debit cards', **at least not without qualification**."

Comment: Kris, edited as requested. @Martha, I agree that there is a qualification. And I concede that debit cards preceded stored value debit cards. I am seeing the usage of "debit card" shifting diachronically ("debit card" only introduced in 1983/7, depending on whether you believe the Danes or the Brits; Stored Value cards mid 90s). Common usage is blurring into the notion that a piece of plastic with a mag stripe, 16 digits, and a Visa logo is a debit card. The stored value card walks and quacks like a debit card; in the collective mind of Gen iPod, it *is* a debit card.

Comment: (Interesting St. Louis Fed discussion about stored value cards at http://www.stlouisfed.org/publications/br/articles/?id=552). First sentence, "Stored value cards resemble a typical debit card..." The Fed thinks it quacks like a debit card, too, with some important distinctions.

Answer (score 5):

You have used the correct term from the user point of view. As a card-user you are expected to speak plain English.

**I *refill* my card.**
**I *recharge* my card.**
**I *top-up* my card.**

The correct 'technical' term will be some thing related to "crediting your card account".

Comment: Do you really use any of these, in the USA, in reference to debit cards?

Comment: @Marthaª You would *better* use. People at the bank don't expect you to come with competency in banking terminology. They expect you to *know what you are saying*. It's true in any geography, including the US.

Comment: Just my opinion, but _top up_ sounds awkward on either side of the teller window (even though it's pretty obvious what you mean). I think any of these suggestions would be fine with a card that has a max amount, however, in cases where there is no max amount, I'd be more inclined to something like "I add funds to my card," in lieu of "refill" or "top up".

Comment: I need to disappoint Kristina - there is always a bank involved somewhere (at least in the US) - and the money has to be credited to an account in an entity authorised by various banking laws and authorities. What is actually a "bank account", but simply how computation people index a transaction channel.

Comment: "top-up" is a common UK term, which I've never heard in the US.

Comment: @J.R. I'd find "top up" a perfectly standard word for anything prepaid. I top up my phone credit, and when I had a 3V card (a sort of debit card thingy, not tied to a bank account), I topped up that, too. But I'm Irish, and perhaps Yamikuronue is correct that this is not US English.

Comment: Hi @Yamikuronue. I had no idea that "top up" was specific to this side of the Atlantic. Interesting to learn.

Comment: @TRiG Yup, see Martha's answer above for part of the reason the term hasn't caught on over here. The other part is that prepay cellphones are seen as vastly inferior to contract phones, which are considered the standard option, so people rarely discuss refilling their phone either.

Comment: @TRiG & Yamikuronue: I haven't been keeping score, but I believe I've heard "top off" over here more than "top up," particularly when something is currently more than half full, but you plan to refill it anyway, like, "I'll top off the gas tank," or maybe, "I'll plug in my phone tonight, and top off the battery."

Comment: @J.R. I must admit that "top off" is a new one to me. But both the phrase itself and your explanation thereof suggest to me filling something to its upper limit, and that simply doesn't apply to phone credit and the like. I can have (once, in fact, did have) well over €150 on my phone credit. (That was some special offer: upgrade your phone and get loadsa dosh back in credit over the course of the next year. When you use your phone as little as I do, it piles up.)

Comment: *top up* is used in Canada. For instance, pay-as-you-go phone cards have a "minimum montly top-up" in order to stay on the preferred rate plan, regardless of balance. Is this a Canadianism? I suspect not.

Comment: @Kaz It's not a Canadianism, it's just that it's not US-specific. What the rest of the word calls English is a strange tongue in the US. So people on ELU think anything spoken outside the US is not English.

Comment: _"So people on ELU think anything spoken outside the US is not English."_ I think that ELUers in Australia, NZ, UK and the US can  all get an occasional surprise to learn that something sounding distinctively foreign is actually quite common in another part of the world. More often than not, though, we find it interesting, and appreciate the chance to expand our knowledge and horizons. I'm not aware of any allegations that "anything spoken outside the US is not English."

Comment: @Kris, in addition to what J.R. said, this question is specifically about US English.

Comment: @Kris, seems to me this community is fairly rigorous in being mindful of our different locales.

Answer (score 3):

I have a debit card and the bank's web site refers to this as "depositing to the debit card". I also work with a company that sells gift cards, which are essentially store-specific debit cards, and they refer to this as "incrementing the card" internally and as "adding to the card" when talking to customers.

I have a pre-paid cell phone and the phone company talks about "refilling the account".

It is also common to talk about "crediting an account", though this is perhaps a bit more generic.

In short, I don't think there's a single, consistently-used phrase in English. All of the above are used and understood.

Answer (score 3):

In Canada, it is common to *reload* your debit credit card or reload your Starbucks card, or reload your prepaid phone card.

Reload, in the same meaning you would reload a gun, reload a stapler, reload a mechanical pencil, etc. Reload, as in "to add to".

Comment: "Debit credit card" sounds like a contradiction in terms: is it a debit card (you're spending your own money) or a credit card (you're spending the issuer's money)?

Comment: @Marthaª: If I had to venture a guess, I think there's a missing "/" there; i.e.: "it is common to _reload_ your debit/credit card," where "debit/credit card" refers to, say, any number of [reloadable prepaid Visa cards](http://usa.visa.com/personal/cards/prepaid/index.html).

Answer (score 2):

In these situations I say that I deposited cash (or a check) into my bank account. It's implicitly understood that your debit card is linked to your bank account, so the debit card itself isn't mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I would go with **"I replenished my debit card."**

**From Merriam-Webster's online dictionary:**

re·plen·ish/riˈpleniSH/

Verb:

1. Fill (something) up again.
2. Restore (a stock or supply of something) to the former level or condition.

Answer (score 1):

You could say: 
- I am going to the bank **[to credit](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/credit)** my account.

Comment: Nobody I know would say that.  They'd say, "I am going to the bank to make a deposit." or even more informally "I gotta go put money in my account."

Comment: The bank folks talk bankese all right, but not the customers.

Comment: How about, I am going to credit my banker for his efforts in getting me a loan?

Comment: @Jim My bank calls it this on the monthly statements (there are "credits", "checks", and "debits" sections), and I use the same terminology.  +1

Comment: @Izkata- Yes, your bank will call it that, but no normal person does.

Comment: @jim, we don't know Izkata.  Let's rephrase that to "...no layperson does." :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, It's "Credit". "I just credited my debit card with 200 dollars."

Everything else on here is either jargon or incorrect.

Here's the dictionary's way of defining Credit from Dictionary.com

Under the ways Credit is used in accounting (to Credit a debit card is an act of accounting)

10 accounting

a. acknowledgment of an income, liability, or capital item by entry on the right-hand side
 of an account

b. the right-hand side of an account

c. an entry on this side

d. the total of such entries

e. Compare debit ( as modifier ): ***credit entries***

you credit the entries (money) into an account (debit card)

Comment: Jargon or slang terms are perfectly acceptable answers when the question is "what is it called".

Answer (score 1):

In Australia people say "top up" your account!

Comment: Aref, welcome to ELU. When answering questions, it helps to read them closely: if you'll notice, the asker in this case is interested specifically in US usage.

Answer (score -1):

I think "pay into one's account" is the idiom you're looking for. I don't know about America but that's what you would hear in the UK.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site, and the original question (from 2012) ask what the usage would be in American English. I encourage you to take the [site tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and review the [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) to learn more about how this site functions.