# To express the action of saving money to e-account, which verb should I choose? Recharge or deposit?

Tags: verbs

Suppose I have an e-bank or e-account, to express the action of saving electronic money to that account, which verb should I choose? `recharge` or `deposit`? What's the difference between them?

Comment: Tangentially related (not duplicate): *[What is it called when you “refill” a debit card?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92857)*

Answer (score 2):

Recharge isn't a particularly apt word for the action of saving money to an e-account, as it would imply a level of balance that's "normal" which your saving of money is returning towards. Deposit means

> A sum of money paid into a bank or building society account

and doesn't specify whether the account is branch-based or electronic and so there's no reason not to use that word here.

Comment: I can understand recharge being a candidate, considering some credits cards gets Charged when buying things with. Recharge would probably mean putting money back on it. *But as the answer says, I'd also go with* **deposit**. Arguably working alternative would be **transfer** - can mean transferring into, from to, etc. Also doesn't care about the type of money.

Comment: @Sakatox Yeah, if the question had been concerning credit cards or similar options recharge would have been more appropriate. +1 for transfer, though that's generally used more for the action of taking money out of your account and putting it into someone else's. I don't often see it used for the other way around, though you're absolutely right that it could be used that way.

Comment: Isn't the latest thing "e", as in edeposit or e-deposit?  I say this only half jokingly.  There are so many things that are "e" this or that now.

Comment: @user116032 e-probably.