# What's the word for "putting money on your banking card"?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the correct single word for the bank operation when you need to put cash to your banking card?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. You are posting a single word request, for such questions it is required to add an example sentence. Furthermore some context is needed, since there are a lot of different sorts of **banking cards**. If you describe your situation a little bit better you can expect better answers. Have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out about good questions.

Answer (score 2):

***[Top up](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/top+up)*** is a common expression used with cards:

> - to add money to (a loan, bank account, etc) in order to keep it at a constant or acceptable level
>
>   - ***If it’s a prepaid card, so you need to [top up](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=to%20top%20up%20cards) your account with money before using.*** That’s why it is sometimes known as a pay as you go credit card or a top up credit card.

(AHD)

Comment: is this UK specific or widely understood?
because it seems that top up is a marketing name too

Comment: @Павел - please refer to this older post I have just found. http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/92857/what-is-it-called-when-you-refill-a-debit-card

Comment: well, thanks, it makes sence, at least I see that it is not "debit" ;)